# Anonymous page not working in Angular with OAuth security installed and ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have an Angular v14 application with OAuth installed that is calling an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.
I have a secure part and an non-secured part, but for some reason my non-secured part is not working.

I am using `"@auth0/auth0-angular": "^2.2.2"`.

In the backend API all the calls need authorization except for the not secured `GET All` call, and I know that is working. When I am logging in I can do everything, but when I am not logged in, I can only execute the `GET All` call.

This is my app module `AuthModule`:

```
AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: 'domain',
      clientId: 'clientId',
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
      },
      httpInterceptor: {
        allowedList: [
          `${environment.apiUrl}*`,
         
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
```

And this is the `app.routing.module`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'recipes',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/recipe/recipe.module').then((m) => m.RecipeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'week-menu',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/week-menu/week-menu.module').then(
        (m) => m.WeekMenuModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'shopping-list',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/shopping-list/shopping-list.module').then(
        (m) => m.ShoppingListModule
      ),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'recipes',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];
```

As you can see in the routing module, only the `shopping-list.module` is authenticated. If the user is authenticated or not, some buttons are visible. That is also working.

So when I go to the path 'recipes' I get an error:

> Login is required

and the call to the backend is not executed. But that is probably because of my interceptor.

```
providers: [
    HttpClient,
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

So when the user is not logged in, my application is probably not able to add the bearer token in the request to the API (`GET All`).

How can I make sure that the user is able to view the recipes page without logging in?

I tried creating a custom interceptor, but then nothing was working.

Comment: Have you tried doing this with no AuthGuard? What happens when you have no kind of authorization? Also, do you have any kind of authorization on the backend? If you added authentication/authorization on the backend, the calls ACTUALLY reach the backend, it's just that they are blocked in the authentication/authorization middleware and they don't reach your controllers

Comment: @GabrielStancu yes I have security installed in the backend and there it is working. When I disable the AuthGuard on my routes then those routes are not secured. that is not the problem here. In the mean time I wrote a custom interceptor based on the Auth0 Interceptor and now it is working.